# Vagrant Chef and Apache2 (404 not found)

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am attempting to get to grips with vagrant and chef. If I download the opscode cookbook apache2 from git, checkout latest tag and do the following in my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "chef/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe("apt")
    chef.add_recipe("apache2")
    chef.add_recipe("apache2::mod_rewrite")
  end
end
```

...I end up with a VM with apache installed and working but (after some digging I found that) /var/www is not the documentroot it is infact /etc/apache2/htdocs

Do I need to add a line to my Vagrantfile to configure the document root?

Any help would be appreciated!

Guest Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution fits in the Vagrantfile :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "precise32"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8080, guest: 80

    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|

        chef.add_recipe "apt" 
        chef.add_recipe "apache2"

        chef.json = { 
            "apache" => {
                "default_site_enabled" => true,
                "docroot_dir" => "/vagrant"
            }
        }

    end

end
```

Doing this way you don't need to launch a site by SSH each time you "Vagrant up".

Comment: Thankyou very much, concise and just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

No. In Vagrantfile you configure your virtual machine (such as memory, hostname, ports) and recipes that should be run (in provision part). But changing apache document root requires changing the apache recipe. Check out the [attributes/default.rb](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2/source) and change the required path.

Comment: Wrong link to attributes/default.rb => https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/attributes/default.rb

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Linux distribution, for Debian/Ubuntu DocumentRoot defaults to `/var/www` while for RHEL/CentOS/Oracle/Fedora/SUSE it defaults to `/var/www/html`, for Arch Linux it defaults to `/srv/http`.

Suppose you are using tag 1.7.0.

You can

1. (easier) edit the `default['apache']['docroot_dir']` in [attributes/default.rb](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/1.7.0/attributes/default.rb)
2. Use [Custom JSON data](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) in `Vagrantfile` (equivalent to node.js for a chef-solo run) to override the default values.

> **NOTE**: make sure you edit the right distribution related block

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it was actually fairly basic, a cursory glance at the output during vagrant up gave the answer away.

```
[2013-08-25T14:30:51+00:00] INFO: execute[a2dissite default] sending restart action to service[apache2] (delayed)
```

By default apache disables the default site. ssh ing into the instance and running

```
sudo a2ensite default
sudo service apache2 restart
```

fixes things.

Looking at attributes/default.rb I found this line:

```
  default['apache']['default_site_enabled'] = false
```

Now I am not sure on the best method for altering this attribute. (directly in this file? I doubt it)